# MomentJs output Date of toDate() is incorrect

Tags: javascript, angularjs, momentjs

I've started using momentJs in an Angular/Typescript project. (Included incase it's relevant in any way although I very much doubt it)

In the run method of my module I call

```
moment.locale(window.navigator.language);
```

which correctly sets the locale to en-GB in my instance. Further down the line I use moment to parse a GB time.

when doing the following:

```
var mom = moment("24/11/2015 00:00:00");
```

for example. This populates a new moment object using the defaults set on the moment global (If i understand how it should work correctly). moms date is set to 2016-12-11T00:00:00.000Z. This clearly means it's parsed the given string in en-US instead of en-GB which was set via Locale in a default setting prior to this call. Is there anything I've missed in configuration/setup of moment which would make this not work?
I've also inspected the _locale property of my variable. mom._locale is set to en-gb and I can see the L,LL,LLL etc etc formats are all en-GB formatted values (as they should be).

running mom.toDate(); unsurprizingly returns the 2016 date stored internally by the moment object.

Some misc information I forgot to include:

I am using the latest release of momentjs from NuGet (Version 2.10.6 at time of writing) and I've included moment-with-locales.js in my HTML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I got around this by fetching the locale data from moment and just passing it into the format parameter. Considering the example input of "24/11/2015 00:00:00" I would structure my format as below:

```
var format = moment.localeData().longDateFormat('L') + " " + moment.localeData().longDateFormat("LTS");
```

this generates the format mask of "DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss".

You can mix and match whatever formats you want and this will be locale specific to whatever you set moment.locale("") to be (presuming you have the locale information setup in moment already)

This is a crazy workaround and I'm surprised that moment doesn't presume locale information as default when parsing. TJCrowder has raised an issue on Github with the moment guys which I suggest anyone who cares should comment on. https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/2770

Answer (score 2):

Using any recent version of MomentJS, you should see why in the console:

> Deprecation warning: moment construction falls back to js Date. This is discouraged and will be removed in upcoming major release. Please refer to https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/1407 for more info.

[image]

Unless you specify a format string, MomentJS relies on the `Date` object's parsing, and unfortunately, regardless of locale the `Date` object will, with a string using `/`, assume U.S. format. One of the many, many things that aren't quite right with `Date`.

You'll need to use a format string, or supply the string in the simplified ISO-8601 format used by `Date`. From [**Parse > String**](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string/):

> When creating a moment from a string, we first check if the string matches known ISO 8601 formats, then fall back to `new Date(string)` if a known format is not found.
>
> ```
> var day = moment("1995-12-25");
> ```
>
> **Warning**: Browser support for parsing strings is inconsistent. Because there is no specification on which formats should be supported, what works in some browsers will not work in other browsers.
>
> For consistent results parsing anything other than ISO 8601 strings, you should use String + Format.

Comment: Interestingly, `moment("24/11/2015 00:00:00", window.navigator.language);` works, but isn't documented. The documentation says that you can pass a locale as the *third* argument, not the second.

Comment: Interesting. I was looking at getting the language format that moment has stored in its locale information and passing it in as the 2nd parameter, but this seems like a more elegant solution (even if undocumented)

Comment: Double interestingly, when the format is passed in of navigator.language (In my instance en-GB) it actually parses 24/11/2015 to a date object whose value is 22/01/2015 So it doesn't moan about parsing, but appears to parse it into a date object a little wrong. I'll continue on my track of getting the locale format out of moment.

Comment: @Skintkingle: Gah, you're right, I should have checked the date! BTW: https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/2770 (I've just edited it, having got it wrong to start with).

Comment: Ha, Haha, Hahaha. Are we all ready for a hacky hack. 3, 2, 1. Answer!

Answer (score 0):

You're probably better off passing the format to moment directly and validating the string before hand. This will ultimately reduce the amount of debugging you'll need to do and get you up and running straight away.

`var mom = moment("24/11/2015 00:00:00", "DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss");`

You could try the new(ish) [Intl API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl) but browser support is limited (IE11+), so I would recommend having a user select the month in a dropdown or something to force them to input a certain way.

Comment: what's the proposition when I dont know the locale that's in use (And as such cannot hard code a format at that time). My understanding was setting locale will use moments already initialized locale information, and passing the navigators language will (more often than not) get the current users language format. Also your parse format is in en-US which is not desired when the users locale is en-GB (or anything that doesn't use that format)

Comment: I've swapped the parse format. Where is the data coming from? If it's user supplied you need to validate it, e.g. force the user to input it a certain way, or select the format. If it's from a database one would hope it has the information attached about how it's formatted. If not, it's a case of manually improving the data...

Comment: I dont see why I should restrict a user input to be a format that is not their locale. That kind of goes against the entire globalization concept. I need to validate they have put in a valid Date, absolutely, but I shouldnt restrict it to a very specific date format that may not be their locale.

Comment: Ah, sorry. Detecting the date format automatically is a tricky business, much easier if you're really concerned about it is to either use dropdowns for the month or allow the user to select the formatting. The `window.navigator.language` isn't suitable for choosing the date formatting because it can't determine which English speaking countries format to use. Intl API is better, but IE11+ support only. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl